# Static assets don't show up for flask on elastic beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How do you get aws elastic beanstalk to recognize your static assets in your flask app? I did the standard /.ebextensions/python.config couple of YAML lines a la:

```
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
    "/static/": "static/"
```

All of my calls to assets in templates are wrapped in "{{url_for('static', filename='img/office.jpg')}}" type things.

But no images, styles or javascript shows up on page load. Here is an example log file 404. 
IP - - [25/Feb/2013:21:48:13 +0000] "GET /static/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 404 328 "http://xyz.elasticbeanstalk.com/"

Am I missing something obvious? Everything runs great on my local, just static assets dont load once i git aws.push

Comment: I'm having the same problem, except with bottle. I have a bunch of subfolders in /static so in bottle I have a route saying `@route('/static/:path#.+#')` and it works fine, but I can't get it to work in beanstalk. Hopefully someone has an answer for us!

Answer (score 12):

It can be done also through Elastic Beanstalk Panel:

**Configuration -> Software Configuration - > Static Files**

and then

[image]

just as an alternative option

Comment: This doesn't work. It sets the property `aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles`, which is not recognized by Flask. You need to create a variable in the `aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python` scope manually.

Comment: hi @MylesBaker, maybe there are new updates but I assure you it does. The configuration is currently working on my deploys both for Flask and Node in Elastic Beanstalk

Comment: I can confirm this is working in April 2020. I tried manually configuring my .ebextensions/helloworld.config file as other solutions suggested, but that only created additional problems. Also https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html#configuration-options-recommendedvalues seems to suggest the properties established in the console override those established in the config file. If you're having troubles, consider trying this solution first! (unlike me)

Answer (score 6):

As of this writing, after spending many hours fighting with AWS EB's config, I gave up trying to make the static files work the way we all expect and updated my Flask app creation to:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/s')
```

This renders urls like `/s/scripts/my-script.js` and since I always use `url_for('static', ...)` in my code and templates, everything continued to work outside of AWS as well.

**Update on 9/30/2013**: I can pretty much guarantee that the `staticFiles` settings are completely ignored in AWS EB's Python container.

The change I suggested above has the undesirable downside of routing all static file requests through Flask (maybe, more accurately, WSGI.) That's not very hard to fix, though.

Create an Apache conig file at your project root, named **app-httpd.conf**:

```
Alias /s /opt/python/current/app/static
<Directory /opt/python/current/app/static>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

This config tells Apache to take over any requests for URLs starting with `/s`, same prefix we chose for our static files, and serve files from our app's *static* folder.

Create this file at **.ebextensions/custom-apache.config**:

```
container_commands:
  add_apache_conf:
    command: "cp app-httpd.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d"
```

This file will be used during the app deployment and will copy the new .config file to a directory from which Apache is configure to load all .config files it sees.

Comment: [What is the relationship between `.ebextensions/*.config` files and `.elasticbeanstalk/optionsettings.*` files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27907203/656912)?

Comment: The **.elasticbeanstalk** directory, as far as I understand, keeps local settings for your project. These settings are used by the `eb` command line tools, including when you run `git aws.push`. I personally stopped using these tools and wrote my own scripts using their API. In my case, for Python, I use the Boto package. The stuff in **.ebextensions** are included with your app when it's deployed or updated. It contains settings or commands that will be executed in your app servers upon deployment.

Comment: @sergiopereira Thank you, your comment about the problems with the `staticfiles` settings helped me solve my issue.

Answer (score 6):

4+ years later, I'm able to get static files working using:

(file: `.ebextensions/WHATEVER_NAME.config`)

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python
    option_name: StaticFiles
    value: /static/=PATH/FROM/MY/APP/BASE/DIR/TO/STATIC/DIR/
```

...in my case, this was

```
    value: /static/=distrib/static/
```

I found that changing my

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

to

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static')
```

was neither necessary nor sufficient. When I only set static_url_path but not StaticFiles, it didn't work; when I set StaticFiles but not static_url_path, it worked fine.

<sarcasm>Elastic Beanstalk is super straightforward and well documented!</sarcasm>

Comment: I needed to read this answer a few times before it made sense, but this is the correct answer. As @sergiopereira stated, the "staticfiles settings are completely ignored in AWS EB's Python container."

Comment: This worked for me based on your answer   aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
    /static: static

Answer (score 1):

I spent a goodly amount of time trying to figure this out and sort through these suggestions. I've made comments on the answers that were still relevant in 2020. Here's the TL;DR of the solution I encountered:

- The `static files` section in the `Modify Software` screen under the `Configuration` left navigation pane on the Elastic Beanstalk UI sets the property `aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles`. This configuration does not map to the `static_url_path` which Flask needs to find the static assets.
- The correct property to set is `StaticFiles`, which can be set by adding a `.config` file to the `.ebextensions` directory.

[Read more here.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-container.html#python-namespaces)

Answer (score 0):

A strange thing that I found to solve this issue was editing my .gitignore file.  It had included removing the /dist folders, and that included the dist folders that my CSS was generated into.  So the css files were actually missing when I deployed.

Hope this may help anyone who might be in the same boat.

Answer (score 0):

This problem baffled me for a bit because it worked locally. No need to change config. I change line 1 to line 2 in my html file and it worked. Keep static folder in root directory and also keep config at /static/:/static/.

```
 1 <link rel="stylesheet" href={{url_for('static',filename='style.css')}}/>

2 <link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='style.css') }}">
```

may be the quotes around the href.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Myles Baker's solution, but did not work as upon deployment I received the error -

```
ERROR   Invalid option specification (Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python', OptionName: 'StaticFiles')
```

I ended up using the following code in my .ebextensions/WHATEVER_NAME.config -

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
    /html: statichtml
    /images: staticimages
```

Which is a straight copy/paste from here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-cfg-staticfiles.html

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    PYTHONPATH: "/var/app/current:$PYTHONPATH"
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
    /static: static
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem where, strangely enough, all files from `static/img/` were being served, but anything in `static/css/` or `static/js/` were simply not being served.

To fix this I opened `.elasticbeanstalk/optionsettings.app-env` from the root directory of the Flask source and edited this block of code to be

```
[aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python]
NumProcesses=1
NumThreads=15
StaticFiles=/static/.*=
WSGIPath=application.py

[aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles]
```

Note that `StaticFiles` actually takes a regular expression, so in `/static/.*` the `.*` allows for any path after `/static/`

Comment: [What is the relationship between `.ebextensions/*.config` files and `.elasticbeanstalk/optionsettings.*` files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27907203/656912)?

Comment: This answer is significantly out-of-date.